# How to debug SocialEngine through an IDE

Tags: eclipse, socialengine

I've downloaded SocialEngine source code, added few plugins to the website I'm testing.

Now, I'm trying to customize the plugins' and SocialEngine's code to fit my use cases.

How can I make a change to the source code of any of these plugins through Eclipse and reflect that on my website? I want to be able to debug the source code from Eclipse.

I understand that I need to create a module through SocialEngine SDK and install it via the package manager tool, but, I've already got the module source code for the plugins I mentioned above. So, speaking of a full development IDE like Eclipse, how can I tweak this code and have it deployed to my website and debug through it as well?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For customizations, you should understand, the plugins releases upgrades and bug fixes. So, you should add your work in such ways, that you merge easily with those updates regularly.
For debugging you should understand and follow zend framework application, on which socialengine is built.
Would be better, if you ask specific issues you are having in development.
Then, you would have better answers with insights.
Maybe this is helpful, for now.

Comment: Are you suggesting to build a custom plugin/module on top of the plugins I installed?

Comment: Yes, if customisation is of has much larger functionalities. 
In existing plugins small tweaks can be done in new files. But new plugin is much better way, because you can keep version dependency managed.